# Inception V3 Image Classification

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction, conv-neural-network

How can I understand what features is the Google Inception V3 model using to classify a set of images, what features or pixels of the images are more significant for classifying them?

For instance, if the classifier were to distinguish between a Cheetah and a Leopard, it would probably do so by judging based on their spots. How can I determine what aspects of my images the classifier values most?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not easily answerable, Neural nets in general compose of hierarchical features where in the initial layers the neural net may learn to detect edges and blobs and in the deeper layers it learn more abstract features, so in a n class classification problems, where n might be a large number it is notoriously difficult to interpret what exactly the network learns and uses to classify images. Having said that *Obviously* work has been done,But i will refer you to https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/, this should help you a bit